# How to have a read and an edit view of an input field in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, input

I'm trying to have an edit view and a read view of an input field.
The objective is to edit a number without any kind of format but show it with some specific spacing and decimal places.

To do that I'm using 2 fields but only showing one at any given time.

I also need to save the input value if it has been changed so im using ng-change and ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}" so that i don't do a save request in every key press.

The problem is I keep getting this error "Cannot read property '$$phase' of null"

I leave here a simplified example of my code (although in this website it seems not to show the error, and just misses the item.isInEditMode update)

```js
var app = angular.module('Appp', []);
        app.controller('metadataCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
            $scope.vm = { myItems : {} }

            $scope.vm.myItems = [ {type: "a", value: 34.5},
                                  {type: "a", value: 12.5},
                                  {type: "b", value: 3.15} ];

            $scope.setEditMode = function ( item, val ) {
               item.isInEditMode = val;
            }

            $scope.saveValue = function ( rowRate ) {
                           //do something
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<form ng-app="Appp" name="myForm" ng-controller="metadataCtrl">
   
          <div ng-repeat="item in vm.myItems">
              <input type="number"
                   ng-if="!item.isInEditMode"
                   ng-focus="setEditMode(item, true)"
                   ng-value="item.value | number : 2"
                   step="0.01"
                   max="99999999999999"
                   min="0"
                   step-message="{name} can only have a maximum of 2 decimal places"/>
            <input type="number"
                   ng-if="item.isInEditMode"
                   step="0.01"
                   max="99999999999999"
                   min="0"
                   step-message="{name} can only have a maximum of 2 decimal places"
                   ng-blur="setEditMode(item, false)"
                   ng-model="item.value"
                   ng-change="saveValue( item )"
                   ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}"/>
          </div>
   </form>
```

edit:
if i use just the ng-blur and check if the input.$changed to check if I call my function or not does overcome the $$phase error.

But I still cant focus the hidden input

Comment: editing one input field and showing the edited value in the other input field? is that what you are going to do?

Comment: yes. the objective is to edit a number showing it normaly but then when the user leaves the field, show it with 2 decimal cases always and milions separators etc

Answer (score 0):

I did only a minor change,I hope this is what you expect.If not I'll try again.

```
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="MyCtrl">

          <div ng-repeat="item in vm.myItems">
              <input type="number"
                   ng-if="!item.isInEditMode"
                   ng-focus="setEditMode(item, true)"
                   step="0.01"
                   max="99999999999999"
                   min="0"                   
                   step-message="{name} can only have a maximum of 2 decimal places"
                   ng-model="item.value"
                   disabled
                   />
            <input type="number"
                   ng-if="item.isInEditMode"
                   step="0.01"
                   max="99999999999999"
                   min="0"
                   step-message="{name} can only have a maximum of 2 decimal places"
                   ng-blur="setEditMode(item, false)"
                   ng-model="item.value"
                   ng-change="saveValue( item )"
                   ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}"/>
          </div>
   </form>
```

Comment: this aproach only makes the initial shown input as disabled, right? I want it to be enabled but when the user clicks on it it will become invisible and focus the previously hidden one

Comment: when the user clicks on the input field, it will becomes invisible. when will it become visible again? your requirement is vague. please explain again.

Comment: the setEditMode function takes care of the visibility. (its hooked on blur and on focus)